# '-[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: geolocation, ios8, location, xcode6, cllocationmanager

Can anyone please help in getting fix for fetching location updates in ios8 xcode6 i am getting the crash at             [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

if i place this line of code in

if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
            [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }

then Locationmanager delegates are not called.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exactly same problems.

Then I figured that I ran it on the wrong device (wrong iOS)

locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization
availability iOS 8.0 and later

That's it. Run it on iOS 8 or later. You better use check version to use that method.